How to make mask for material with Volume in compositing?
How to make mask for material with Volume in compositing? I need to change color of clouds, but in scene doesn't produce desired result, so I tried to do it in compositing, but neither ID mask nor Cryptomatte work with Volume. Please tell me how to make that it work?

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you want to do. You have clouds made of a volume, and they have a volume material - which supposedly gives them their color? So why don't you just animate the color of the volume material...? Or am I missing here something?

Yes, there is cube with Volume material as clouds, but color in scene itself for these clouds can't be set up properly. I thought that this could be fixed in compositing, but as it turned out, Pass index doesn't work for Volume materials. Compositing doesn't see it & doesn't allow changing color or making glow or anything else. Maybe there is a way to make compositing work with Volume materials?

Sorry I don't understand why "color in scene itself for these clouds can't be set up properly"? Since you don't show how it is set up, I don't see a reason why it should not work to animate the material color.

Background affects color of clouds & attempts to change it don't lead to desired color, or volume becomes less visible. The only option is to adjust color in compositing.

Do you know the phrase "a picture says more than 1000 words"? I still have no idea what the problem is, what it looks like now and what you want it to look like.

It doesn't matter how it looks & how it should look, because this problem is not only with clouds, but with all objects that have volume materials. And so question consists in the fact that, how to make it so that in compositing it would be possible to make mask for volume materials, so that these materials could be changed in color, made glow or something else?
